# Python Airtable Updating Records from a CSV file

Tags: python, json, csv, flask, airtable

I am pulling data from a CSV file and updating records in Airtable using Python.

Here is the structure of my table (taken from the Airtable REST API Docs in cURL):

```
EXAMPLE REQUEST
curl -X PATCH https://api.airtable.com/v0/APPID/TABLE \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{
  "records": [
    {
      "id": "recxFFcwJn05zDa9u",
      "fields": {
        "Nom": "#########",
        "Prénom": "##########",
        "Status": "Active",
        "CIN": "A111111",
        "Téléphone": "0647386423",
        "Salaire": 10000,
        "Nombre de jours travaillés": 25,
        "Date d'\''entrée": "2021-07-01",
        "Pourcentage Avance": 0.3,
        "Email": "k####@outlook.com",
        "Avance Totale Max": 5000,
        "Nombre d'\''Avances Par Mois": -1,
        "Nombre d'\''Avances Gratuites Par Mois": -1,
        "registry": [
          "reczaZv0kQNmrRrxV",
          "recaghf8vJ6ArxcUO",
          "recDNwmMenWxZddmg",
          "recdo5mKczZjIiX0A",
          "recaqzxAHbAuAFaSp",
          "rec3j7SZbMvtWkVws",
          "recczoO5VxqLVd5IW",
          "recvk4RjioFo9YrhG",
          "recCYEZyjNYZQ1APk",
          "recqWjAk1KhCLWyht",
          "recR9FPzUCg93pHJq",
          "recSnwIfBIT3jK5is",
          "recaKecQCYY6JtRin",
          "recFnYBGvVwV2lQWq",
          "rec5vuSJp9e30c96Z",
          "recY74nsXcKGRBu9L",
          "recsX4XS7CnaZTL9a"
        ],
        "Frais de demande": 10
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "recgeMPZA8dx1ffZ0",
      "fields": {
        "Nom": "B#####",
        "Prénom": "######",
        "Status": "Actif",
        "CIN": "A555555",
        "Téléphone": "066145635",
        "Salaire": 20000,
        "Nombre de jours travaillés": 25,
        "Date d'\''entrée": "2022-05-08",
        "Pourcentage Avance": 0.3,
        "Email": "#####@gmail.com",
        "Avance Totale Max": 2500,
        "Nombre d'\''Avances Par Mois": 3,
        "Nombre d'\''Avances Gratuites Par Mois": 1,
        "Frais de demande": 5
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

I am only interested in updating one fields `Nombre de jours travaillés` using the key: `CIN`

So my CSV file has 2 fields:

```
CIN,Nombre de jours travaillés
```

Here is the steps I've taken:

1- Get the CSV content:

```
with open(file, "rt") as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
        for i, rows in enumerate(csvReader):
            data[i] = rows
```

2- Convert the CSV content to JSON:

```
jsondata = json.loads(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

3- (I'm stuck here...) Adding the JSON data I've converted to the airtable structure to be able to send the PATCH request:

So normally I know I have this structure:

```
data = {
        "records": [
            {
                "fields": {
                    "CIN": "X"
                    "Nombre de jours travaillés": X 
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I need to know how can I insert the JSON I got into this template to send it as a PATCH request.

These are the thoughts I gathered so far:

a) Create an empty template dictionnary and append "fields" items to it:

```
for i in range(len(jsondata)):
        data["records"][i]["fields"]["CIN"] = something
        data["records"][i]["fields"]["Nombre de jours travaillés"] = something
```

b) Create a list "records list" and add the items there, then add the "records" list to data via .append()

3- Take the final `data` json object and send a PATCH request to airtable:

```
endpoint = f"https://api.airtable.com/v0/{os.environ['database']}"

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {os.environ['airtable_key']}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

def patch(table, data):
    url = f"{endpoint}/{table}"
    r = requests.patch(url = url, json=data, headers = headers)
    return r.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# 1- Get the CSV content:
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvf:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
    csv_data = [*csvReader]

# 2 - Create an empty template dictionnary
data = {"records": []}

# 3 - append "fields" items to it:
for row in csv_data:
    data['records'].append(
        {
            "fields": {
                "CIN": row['CIN'],
                "Nombre de jours travaillés": row['Nombre de jours travaillés'],
            }
        }
    )
```